# Is there a way to add rectangles in gridpane and change colors of them

Tags: java, javafx, colors

7. Write a program, which shows the chess board 7. Every black or white cell is a Rectangle object with the corresponding color.

   TIP: To create the check box, define the pane of the GridPane class and 
   within two loops place Rectangle on GridPane with pane.add ()

   This is what my theacher wants.

I try this :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    GridPane pane = new GridPane();

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
            pane.add(new Rectangle(30, 30), i, j);
        }
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise_3_7");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

And I have only black color, how can I change some of those to white?

Comment: re-read the course textbook (or an arbitrary very basic tutorial on javafx) - your teacher certainly will not give you an exercise on matters you can't find out by yourself ..

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop do the following:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(30, 30);
<change the relevant attributes here>
pane.add(rect, i, j);
```

Hint: A Rectangle is a Shape so it sounds like a good idea to read the documentation on Shapes https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html in order to find out what the relevant attributes are for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! i did some changes with if else conditions and i understand where is the problem thank you again